# Issues with Redactor on Local Install

Tags: craft3, plugins, redactor, composer

I loaded redactor. When I try to run the install command 
./craft install/plugin redactor
I get an error back that says craft is a directory.

It appears the plugin may already be installed.
But I do not know the next step to access it.
I thought I might have a Redactor field type available to select but I do not.

Also the plugin store does not load on my local install.
It says plugin store not available at this time.

Under settings > Plugins nothing shows.

Answer (score 2):

Disregard, I loaded redactor in the wrong directory!